# linq help for deep date list

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a class with a list of a 2nd class which has a list of dates.  What is the best way to get the entire list of dates in the top level class?

Given the following:

```
Class 1 contains:

Public List<Class2> Class2List;

Class 2 contains:

List<DateTime> DateList;
```

What is the best way to get the entire list of dates in Class 1?  I know I can loop through each of the Class 2 items and then get the list that way, but I’m hoping there is a cleaner way with LINQ.

```
List<DateTime> tempDateList;

Foreach (var Class2 in Class2List)
{


Foreach (var dt in Class2.DateList)
{
            tempDateList.Add(dt);
}

}

Return tempDateList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple really;

```
var tempDateList = Class2List.SelectMany(x => x.DateList).ToList();
```

- `SelectMany(x => x.DateList)` *essentially* performs like an inner loop here, creating a continuous sequence (all of the `DateList` from the first class, all of the `DateList` from the second class, etc)
- `ToList()` creates a concrete `List<DateTime>` from that data
- the `var tempDateList` is fully static typed, and infers `List<DateTime>` from the expression

Answer (score 4):

```
var tempDateList = Class2List.SelectMany(x => x.DateList()).ToList();
```

Forgot the `ToList` since that is what you want.